# How to receive a python variable from vim

Tags: vimrc

How would I do the following in vim using `pyx` ?

```
let abc = 123
pythonx print (abc)
# >>> NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
```

From above, it looks like python doesn't have access to the `vim` namespace, so is there a way to do the inverse of:

```
pythonx vim.command("let abc=%s" % 123)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vim.eval()` to use Vim variables/expressions from Python. =>

```
# python code
print vim.eval('g:foobar')
```

`pyxeval()` for the other way around.

```
" vim code
:echo pyxeval('somePythonFunc("foo") + 42')
```

Comment: great. Here's my example: `pythonx a=909; vim.command('let a=%s' % a)
echom 'The python variable a is: ' . a`